# plot one in three plots on knitr

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown

I want to run through a script and make many plots, but only in the end plot then out to markdown
 
So what I tried to do is save many plots as a list of plots, but not publish them to markdown.
Second step is go throgh the list and plot one in three plots but for some reason i get only the last plot.

```
#+ setup, include=FALSE

library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'figure/silk-', fig.width = 10, fig.height = 10)

#' Make a list of plots.
#' 
#/* do not show in Markdown
index = 1
plots<-list()
for (let in letters)
{
 plot(c(index:100))
 assign(let,recordPlot())
 plot.new()
 plots[index]<-(let)
 index=index+1
}
#*/go through list of plots and plot then to markdown file
for (p in seq(from = 1, to = length(plots), by =3))
{

    print(get(plots[[p]]))

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code as relics from other programming languages:

- Don't use `assign` at all. People who are allowed to use assign will not use it.
- `plot.new()` creates an empty page. Leave out
- Do not use `get`. It had its uses in S-Plus, but is not helpful nowadays.
- with lists, use `[[`, e.g. `plots[[index]]`
- Most important: What you want makes sense, but standard graphics (e.g. plot) is badly suited for this because it was build with action in mind, not with assignment. Both `lattice` and `ggplot2` graphics are assignment-aware.
- In the example, I use `lapply` as a demonstration of standard R practices. A for-loop will not be slower in this case, because plotting takes most of the time.
- Better use facets or panels for this, instead of many individual plots.

`

```
library(knitr)
library(lattice)
# Make a list of plots.
# do not show in Markdown
plots = lapply(letters[1:3],
    function(letter) {xyplot(rnorm(100)~rnorm(100), main=letter)})

# print can use a list (not useful in this case)    
print(plots)

# go through list of plots and plot then to markdown file
# This only makes sense if you do some paging in between. 
for (p in seq(from = 1, to = length(plots), by =3))
{
  print(plots[[p]])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
1.  I am not sure i understand some of your comments: "People who are allowed to use assign will not use it" (?)
2. you turned the loop  to apply that is great practice, but when i comment out the apply function and use only the last for loop i still get only the last plot documented

Comment: It's a quote from r-help around 2001 when I used assign in a similar job. See http://markmail.org/message/w3hwkqs6e57wbuie and many other places.

Comment: When you comment the lapply function, you get nothing, or better the relics of your last run. Restart R before you re-run

Comment: I don't completely comment it out i ad '/* ' before and '*/' after so it does not show in the md file